# Чтение и запись данных sd карты в Android

Tags: java, android, sd

Необходимо читать и писать данные в память sd карты (желательно иметь возможность указать адрес или смещение записи). SD карта без файловой системы. 
При присоединении карты к телефону появляется файл `/dev/block/mmcblk0`. Как я понял это и есть sd карта. В приложении предоставлены права `write_external_storage` и да они запрашиваются в начале работы приложения.

Телефон рутован. Рут права получены командой

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Все это не помогло прочитать файл `mmcblk0`. Т.е. код

```
new FileInputStream(new File("/dev/block/mmcblk0"));
```

вызывает исключение:

> java.io.FileNotFoundExeption: /dev/block/mmcblk0` (Permission denied)

Вариант с командой

```
dd if="" of=""
```

не подойдет.

Телефон Samsung s8 Android 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку аппарат рутованный, то попробуйте:

```
chmod 0666 /dev/block/mmcblk0
```

посмотрите что из этого получится. По крайней *permission denied* должен уйти

Comment: Данный вариант использовался, не помогло. Пробовал отключить SElinux командой setenforce 1, но телефон перезагружается и не отключает SELinux

Comment: Возможно код Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); не предоставляет root прав процессу приложения, т.е. я могу использовать команды терминала требующие su, но сам код (приложение) не имеет данных прав.

Comment: Получите нормальный рут, потом и пробуйте, иначе это не заработает

Answer (score 0):

На рутованном устройстве, программно (в java коде) запускаем через консоль исполняемые файлы на СИ. Данные файлы уже будут иметь права root.